# How to prevent garbage being read from read end of PIPE in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I have written a small code using pipe and fork. The child process calls child function which writes to the pipe. The parent process calls parent function which reads from the pipe.

The problem comes when the first call of the program after fork() goes to parent function. Here the write end is closed. Now the problem is that the read call is reading some garbage into buf and nread is giving value > 0 . How can this be prevented.

Using Linux 2.6.32-30-generic and gcc 4.4.3. Below is the code::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 16

void parent(int* p);
void child(int* p);

char* msg1 = "hello";
char* msg2 = "bye";

int main()
{
    int pfd[2];
    if(pipe(pfd) == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to create pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fcntl(pfd[0],F_SETFL,O_NDELAY);

    if(fork() == 0)
        child(pfd);
    else
        parent(pfd);

    return 0;
}

void parent(int p[2])
{
    int nread;
    char buf[MSGSIZE];
    buf[0] = '\0';

    close(p[1]);
    for(;;)
    {
        nread = read(p[0] , buf , MSGSIZE);
        if(nread == 0)
        {
            printf("pipe Empty/n");
            sleep(1);
        }
        else
        {
            if(strcmp(buf,msg2) == 0)
            {
                printf("End of conversation\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            else
                printf("MSG=%s\n" , buf);
        }
    }
}

void child(int p[2])
{
    int count;
    close(p[0]);
    for(count = 0 ; count < 3 ; count++)
    {
        write(p[1],msg1 , MSGSIZE);
        sleep(3);
    }
    write(p[1],msg2,MSGSIZE);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You are writing 16 bytes to the pipe, but the string is only 5 bytes (6 with terminating `'\0'`). When you receive garbage, what is `nread`? And what is the string you receive?

Answer (score 4):

One problem is this:

```
char buf[MSGSIZE];
buf[0] = '\0';
```

this only sets the first character in `buf` to the null terminator: the remaining characters in `buf` are unitialized. The `read()` is attempting to read `16` bytes meaning the characters in `buf` will not be null terminated and `printf("%s", buf)` requires that `buf` is null terminated. Even if `buf` had been initialized correctly it would still not be sufficient due to its size being `16` but the `read()` reading `16` also, leaving no room for the null terminator.

A possible fix would be:

```
char buf[MSGSIZE + 1] = ""; /* +1 added to store the null terminator and
                               all characters set to 0 (null terminator). */
```

Another problem is the `write()`s (as commented by [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg)):

```
write(p[1],msg1 , MSGSIZE);
write(p[1],msg2 , MSGSIZE);
```

`msg1` and `msg2` are not `16` bytes long. Change to:

```
write(p[1],msg1 , strlen(msg1));
write(p[1],msg2 , strlen(msg2));
```

Also, `read()` returns `-1` on failure so the following is not sufficient:

```
nread = read(p[0] , buf , MSGSIZE);
if(nread == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Check also for `-1`:

```
else if(nread == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "read() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

See answer from [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) regarding blocking/non-blocking configuration issues.

Comment: Note that with this approach, read() might not return a full string, which might or might not matter depending on how one want to process the read data.

Comment: @nos, I missed the non-blocking configuration. Given that there is a `strcmp()` I think the full string is required.

Answer (score 3):

Your real problem is this line:

```
fcntl(pfd[0],F_SETFL,O_NDELAY);
```

This sets the read end pipe to non-blocking. So every read() call will return as much data as there is in the buffer, or return -1 and set errno to EWOULDBLOCK if there's no data to be read at this particular time.

However, your code does not handle that case, it only checks `if(nread == 0)` and prints out the buffer even if you didn't read anything. So remove that line.

If you do not want to send fixed size messages, or want to keep the read end non-blocking, things becomes more tricky, as you have to account for at least these cases:

- read() returning -1 and sets errno to EWOULDBLOCK (just try read() again).
- read() reads the first 4 bytes of your "message", and the next read returns the rest of the message.
- read() reads the first message, and half of the subsequent message.

i.e. you need some form of framing/delimiters on your messages that you need to handle, unless you just need to stream the content of the pipe further on.

Answer (score 0):

`Read` does not nul-terminate the input.

To print a character buffer that isn't nul-terminated, do like this:

```
printf("MSQ=%.*s\n", nread, buf);
```

If you want to nul-terminate the read buffer you need to make 2 changes.

1 . Increase the size of the buffer to MSGSIZE+1:

```
char buf[MSGSIZE + 1];
```

2 . nul-terminate buf after each read.

```
buf[nread > 0 ? nread : 0] = 0;  // read returns -1 on error
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Also

`msg1` and `msg2` are string literals which are smaller than `MSGSIZE`.

The thing about garbage is this principle called GIGO: garbage in, garbage out.

Don't want garbage in the pipe? Use a drain trap on your kitchen sink.